# How to pass parameter from Angular to CSS in HTML table

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have HTML table in Angular web app.
Get the data from the database via service and display it as text.

One of the columns is Status, so I need to present that variable not as text,
but as a circle of certain color, so if that cell value is "green",
it should show as green circle.

Here is what I have.

CSS (part of Component Styles):

```css
:host ::ng-deep td.circle { 
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  background-color: RED;  <---  need to pass param here
}
```

I define that column as:

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<app-table [attrs]="serviceapi" [monthSelected]="monthSelected" ></app-table>
```

TS for that table:
In constructor:

```js
this.data =  {
  headers: [],
  rows: []
};

ngOnInit() {
  this.tableMetricsService.getTableMetrics(
     JSON.parse(this.attrs).api,
     this.monthSelected
  ).subscribe(response => {
    this.data = response;
    }
  );
}
```

Any idea how to "translate" cell value into the CSS  background-color ?

TIA,

Oleg.

Comment: What if I told you that you can’t? Instead have a class that changes the color to red and a class that changes it to green. Then use ngClass to conditionally add the class to make it the right color.

Comment: Title confused me!

Comment: I suggest you not to handle the design stuff (css changes) inside your ts file. Instead you can use [ngClass] or [class] and change the classes dynamically inside html according to your db response. go throught this link https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:
`<div *ngIf="cell.styleClass == 'circle'" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': cell.value}" [ngClass]="cell.styleClass">
              </div>`

Answer (score 0):

You could put a data attribute on the html and write a corresponding selector:

```css
[data-status="green"] {
  background: green;
}

[data-status="red"] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-status="green">Green</div>
<div data-status="red">Red</div>
```

But I don't see any advantage to this approach over using a regular css class:

```css
.green {
  background: green;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
  <div class="green">Green</div>
  <div class="red">Red</div>
```

Comment: Ray Hatfield, so with your later code sample, if I make in into  td.circle.red and td.circle.green, how do I select one of them if cell value is 'red' or 'green'?  That column is of class circle in external database (kind of data driven development), I don't think I can really add something to mentioned HTML.

Comment: I’m not familiar with how angular works, but surely you have some control over the html rendered in the table. If you can’t put a class on the td, can you wrap the text in a div?

Comment: Actually I got to that HTML for <app-table> and tried something like:  <div *ngIf="cell.styleclass == 'circle' " style="background-color: {{cell.value}};"> </div>   It still shows white circles, you can only see a shadow of a circle.

Comment: Can you inspect it in dev tools and see what’s going on? I can’t troubleshoot your css without being able to see it.